# SQL filtering records by unique column using WHERE clause only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to filter a table to show only the distinct values of a column using only the WHERE clause of an SQL statement.

Below is an example table:

```
Person ID  |  Name  |  City  
----------------------------
    1       person1   city1
    2       person2   city1      
    3       person3   city2
    4       person4   city3
    5       person5   city1
```

I want to get the distinct cities like the following output:

```
City
----
city1
city2
city3
```

However my application restricts me to only specify a WHERE clause.
So the basic format that I'm allowed is this:

```
select city from table1 where __________;
```

UPDATE: I've also tried and found that the SELECT statement is taking all columns (*) as opposed to that single column so I cannot use:

```
select * from table1 where 1=1 group by city;
```

Comment: There's no way to get distinct values using WHERE. If the application is badly coded and allows SQL Injection you might try `WHERE 1=1 GROUP BY city`

Comment: Is it possible to implement there the group by clause as well? -> where 1=1 group by city

Comment: `select distinct city from table1` Is your applcation also restricting the DISTINCT keyword?

Comment: @Mihai Read the question again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This in a `where` clause will have the desired effect.

```
PersonId IN (SELECT MAX(PersonId) FROM table1 GROUP BY city)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
select * 
from table1 
where 
    PersonID IN
    (
        SELECT MIN(PersonID) AS MinID
        FROM table1
        GROUP BY City
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

SQL provides a keyword 'DISTINCT' to show only the distinct values of a column. That is a direct way and there is no need of using WHERE clause. Another case would be you can use GROUP BY clause along with WHERE clause to get the distinct values something like: select city from table1 where 1=1 group by city;

Comment: `DISTINCT` deduplicates based on all selected columns, not a single one! see e.g.
>>> If the DISTINCT keyword is specified, a query eliminates rows that are duplicates according to the columns in the SELECT clause <<<
— https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/sqlref/sql-reference-select-all-distinct.html